# How to remotely detect another machine's utorrent version with nmap?

Tags: bittorrent, nmap

How can I use `nmap` to find out the utorrent version installed on a PC by scanning it from another PC on the same subnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the nmap-service-probes database, it looks like nmap can't detect which version of uTorrent is running.

Answer (score 0):

uTorrent is able to randomise port, so using nmap to detect uTorrent can take long since you have to scan all tcp ports.

Regardless of this fact, nmap tells me :
tcp open  ssl/http uTtermiorrent utserver web interface

If I scan my uTorrent port using -sV option (version detection). It returns nothings.
If you connect using netcat (nc, ncat, socat), there is nothing being returned either when probing for the protocol. (beside a "invalid request")

So unless you manage to find a fingerprint (a output on a connection to utorrent port), you are not gonna figure which version of uTorrent is being used.
I think this is not feasible using network probes :-?